# SQL Server Stored Procedure doesnt appear to be called

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

The syntax of my code in MS Access appears to be correct.

I can run the stored procedure manually in SQL and get the correct result.

When I try to call the stored procedure from MS Access using ADO nothing appears to happen; any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Combo13_LostFocus()

Dim P1 As Integer

P1 = Forms![Frm_Ws10a]![Frm_WS10b]![Combo13].Column(0)

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim CN As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter

Dim adstring As Variant

Set CN = New ADODB.Connection

CN.ConnectionString = "Driver=SQL 
Server;Server=LDXFBHD013492   \SQLEXPRESS;Database=xxxx;Trusted_Connection=YES;"
CN.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = CN
    .CommandText = "dbo.usp_update_consequenceweighting"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .Parameters.Refresh
    Set prm = .CreateParameter("@ITID", adInteger, adParamInput)
   prm.Value = P1

End With

Set rs = cmd.Execute

Me.Recalc
Me.Refresh
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally `parameters.refresh` identifies and creates parameters for you. You don't normally need to call `CreateParameter` to manually add them afterwards. I would use debug mode to inspect your parameters inside the code to see if it's what expect. Then I would interrogate the SQL table directly in SSMS. Then I would use SQL Profiler to capture the SP call and see if there is anything unexpected. If no error is reported then my guess is that you're not passing in the parameter value that you expect, and data is not changing as you expect.

Comment: Do you have `SET NOCOUNT ON` in the proc code? If not, add it.

Comment: I have added to Set nocount on into the stored proc, but still cant get the code right to call the procedure. If I drop the parameters.refresh I get an error saying "Stored Procedure xxx - is expected the variable @itid". Guidance please

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the .parameters.append in your code below

```
With cmd
.ActiveConnection = CN
.CommandText = "dbo.usp_update_consequenceweighting"
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.Parameters.Refresh
Set prm = .CreateParameter("@ITID", adInteger, adParamInput)
```

Try adding the parameter.append instead of setting it

```
With cmd
.ActiveConnection = CN
.CommandText = "dbo.usp_update_consequenceweighting"
.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
.parameter.append .createparameter("@ITID", adInteger, adParamInput, 50, [Value or variable here])
.execute 1
End With
```